Can Anaconda3 / Conda Maintain Pristine Base Environment?
I would like to have my base conda environment to be pristine (i.e. installed with the least amount of packages possible).
Right now, my base environment has a few dozen packages in them, and I'm concerned I'm creating conflicts with any new environments I'm creating for older versions of Python.
My hope is I can have the proper versions available to VSCode Python projects without conflicts from older projects when I create a new env in conda.

I don't understand your question. My hope is I can have the proper versions available to VSCode Python projects without conflicts from older projects when I create a new env in conda. - that is exaclty what an env is for.

What you need to do is : 1. Install miniconda or another minimal conda installation 2. For each of your projects, create a new env. Above all: "never install to base" and your base will always be as it was from the start.

You can start with removing the packages in your base conda you don't need necessarily.
I would suggest always create virtual environments and install dependencies as per the need of project. If the requirements of 2 projects differ a lot, create a new virtual environment. You can always delete a virtual env without worrying about affecting your base conda environment. That will help you maintain even different python versions if you want.
I assume you know defining env paths and creating virtual environments using python or conda. For reference:
python -m venv env_name

.\env_name\Scripts\activate # activation
deactivate                  # deactivation

conda create -n test_env python=3.10.14 anaconda
#Activate
conda activate test_env
#Deactivate
conda deactivate

Finally, you can add paths to your base environment in your new venv, in case you need dependencies that are in your base environment.

export PATH=path_to_base_conda:$PATH
Hope this helps!

